# Potential strategy in a random game

Tags: probability, game-theory, gambling

Suppose there are two betting games $G_1$ and $G_2$, the outcomes of which are entirely independent of player input.

The expected return for a single iteration of $G_1$ is $r_1$ and for $G_2$ is $r_2$, these returns being a percentage of your bet.

Design a game $G$ where you start by choosing either $G_1$ or $G_2$, and you have a chance of getting to play again, and you again choose between the two games.

Suppose if you choose $G_1$ the chance of playing again is $p_1$ and for $G_2$ is $p_2$.

If you take the strategy of always choosing $G_1$, then the overall expected return of $G$ is $$\frac{r_1}{1-p_1}.$$

If we assume that $$\frac{r_1}{1-p_1} = \frac{r_2}{1-p_2},$$

Is this enough to conclude that $G$ has no optimal strategy and that the overall return is the same regardless of your choice at each stage?

If not, what conditions can we place on $r_1,r_2,p_1,p_2$ to ensure that $G$ has no optimal strategy?

Comment: Long term, both options are equivalent, but that certainly is not true short term. More specifically, the game with less variance of results will most likely do better short term.

Comment: I am talking long term strategy though.

Comment: In that case, I see no difference.

Comment: How do we know that there is no optimal strategy though, like choosing some pattern, say $G_1$, $G_2$, $G_1$, $G_2$, ... which will result in a higher expected return in the long run? You get to choose which game to play at every stage.

Comment: Yes, but the strategy is independent of stage.

Comment: Ahh your comment was like a lightbulb switching on in my mind. Thankyou!

Comment: Another way to look at it  is that you have an MDP with two states, and you compute the maximum expected reward by writing the Bellman equations.  If $r_*$ is the optimal reward, you compute $r_* = \min r$ such that $r_1 + p_1r \leq r$ and $r_2 + p_2r \leq r$, where the two constraints come from the two possible strategies.  The constraints satisfied by equality define the optimal strategy.